# How to represent the RFC-3339 `-00:00` offset in Go?

Tags: go, time

RFC-3339 Section 4.3 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-4.3) defines the `-00:00` offset as the following, which is different than `Z` or `+00:00`.

```
4.3. Unknown Local Offset Convention

   If the time in UTC is known, but the offset to local time is unknown,
   this can be represented with an offset of "-00:00".  This differs
   semantically from an offset of "Z" or "+00:00", which imply that UTC
   is the preferred reference point for the specified time.  RFC2822
   [IMAIL-UPDATE] describes a similar convention for email.
```

However, I'm not sure how to represent this in Go. When I parse a time with `-00:00` and format it, I get a `Z` offset. For example:

- Input: `2018-01-01T00:00:00-00:00`
- Output: `2018-01-01T00:00:00Z`

Here's some example code (https://play.golang.org/p/CVmNnhaSiiT):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := "2018-01-01T00:00:00-00:00"
    fmt.Println("Input  " + t)
    p, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, t)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        t2 := p.Format(time.RFC3339)

        fmt.Println("Output " + t2)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think Go's `time` package has a concept of an unknown offset; it's of no particular use. If the offset is genuinely unknown, the time itself is somewhat useless, as any interpretation could be inaccurate by +/- 12 hours - enough that the even date is likely to be off by +/- 1 day.

Comment: When using `-00:00` the time is accurate because the RFC says "the time in UTC is known". It's just that the offset is unknown, so for example, if we have a time `2018-01-01T12:00:00-00:00` we know the exact time, but not the offset, e.g. whether the time is `2018-01-01T11:00:00-01:00` or `2018-01-01T13:00:00+01:00`.

Comment: In which case, its locale is UTC. It is not the duty of a time to offer any information outside of identifying an instance in time. A time that says "at noon UTC but I don't know in what locale it actually happened" is referencing an "it" which is irrelevant to `time.Time`.

Answer (score 4):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> ```
> import "time"
> ```
>
> RFC3339, RFC822, RFC822Z, RFC1123, and RFC1123Z are useful for
>   formatting; when used with time.Parse they do not accept all the time
>   formats permitted by the RFCs.

---

> Go does not accept all the time formats permitted by the RFCs.

The Go `time.Time` type uses integers which, unlike floating-point, have no concept of plus and minus zero. The results for parsing offsets of `-00:00` and `+00:00` are identical.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var err error
    var minus, plus time.Time
    t := "2018-01-01T00:00:00-00:00"
    minus, err = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, t)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    t = "2018-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
    plus, err = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, t)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(minus, plus, minus.Equal(plus), minus == plus)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Urf8VlKYoMH

Output:

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC 2018-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC true true
```

Comment: Regarding "they do not accept all the time formats permitted by the RFCs", the `-00:00` offset is accepted because it parses without an error. However, it seems the conversion may be lossy.

Comment: @Grokify: `time.Parse` does not accept a distinction between plus zero and minus zero offset formats.

Comment: @Grokify: I suggest you to take a look at the actual [code](https://golang.org/src/time/format.go). When parsing a negative offset, the only thing done is invert the positive offset calculated. So as stated here, an integer -0 is equal to +0 and simply inverting it, the information about it gets lost.

Comment: I agree. "the information about it gets lost" is why I said the conversion is lossy.

Answer (score 2):

PeterSO's answer is perfect IMHO. If you need to act differently based on the information that the offset is unknown, then this might help you.

You can build your own time data type:

```
type MyTime struct {
    // based on time.Time so we can do all normal time.Time stuff
    time.Time

    offsetUnknown bool
}

func ParseRFC3339(s string) (MyTime, error) {
    time, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, s)
    if err != nil {
        return MyTime{}, err
    }

    return MyTime{
        Time: time,
        // maybe this condition needs improvement in case of false positives
        offsetUnknown: strings.Contains(s, "-00:00"),
    }, nil
}
```

Any functions you need to behave differently based on `offsetUnknown` you can then override on the `MyTime` struct. Here one example:

```
func (s MyTime) Format(layout string) string {
    out := s.Time.Format(layout)
    // again this is probably not the best solution
    if layout == time.RFC3339 && s.offsetUnknown {
        out = strings.Replace(out, "+00:00", "-00:00", -1)
    }
    return out
}
```